# When does the "delete" button appear beneath a post?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, deletion

Below posts I normally see "share", "edit", and "flag" buttons, but sometimes a "delete" button also appears. How is it decided that this extra button appears?

Comment: If you have permission to delete it, e.g. your reputation is sufficiently high and the score on the answer is sufficiently low; or if you posted the answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:If I delete my question or answer how can others  keep track of connected discussions?

Comment: @Narasimham, that is indeed a problem. I suggest only deleting posts that are no longer relevant.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, it should be feature of the *system !* Deletion of connected discussions should not be left to judgment of any user, right?

Comment: @Narasimham, the users *are* the system. There are limitations for deletion: you can't delete a question that has answers with positive score. I think it's only good that users can do a bit of self-moderation and remove unnecessary content they removed themselves. In special cases moderators can undelete posts.

Answer (score 8):

At the moment you only have the option of deleting posts that you have created. The criteria under which users can delete their own posts is described in the [MSE deletion faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221):

> ### When *can't* I delete my own post?
>
> You can't delete *answers* that have been [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about).
>
> You can't delete any *question* that:
>
> - has an [upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471), or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
>
> You can't delete *any* of your questions or answers if you haven't *registered* your account (that is, associated an OpenID with it).

[Certain users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (as well as ♦-moderators) also have the ability to vote to delete posts of *other users*. This is also explained in the faq.

If you *don't* have the ability to (vote to) delete a post, the "delete" button will not appear.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: Are the rules the same for meta?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: I'm pretty sure the rules are the same throughout the network (meta-sites included). At least, I've never seen anything to suggest that meta-sites are treated differently in this respect.